# Phpmailer dropping name value on html emails, but working with plain text?

Tags: mysql, arrays, phpmailer, php

I am using phpmailer to send out newsletters, It seems to work out and sends out plain text emails ok, but for some reason when sending html emails drops the persons name, where as plain text works fine and shows the name.

When it sends the emails it brings this up on the result page, so it seems it isnt getting the name, but I cant see why ?.

```
Mail sent to: - crea@cruiseit.co.uk
 Mail sent to: Toms Tackle Tom Sawyer - crea@cruiseit.co.uk
Mail sent to: - crea2k@o2.co.uk
```

With HTML I get : Dear , here are your {fuel} prices :
with plain text I get : Dear Bob, here are your {fuel} prices :

Does the following code look ok ?

```
              <?php
                  $formid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[token]);
                              $templatequery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addmailinglistmessage WHERE cf_id = '$formid'") or die(mysql_error());
                              $templateData = mysql_fetch_object($templatequery);

                              $gasoiluserTemplate = $templateData->gasoilusers;
                              $dervuserTemplate = $templateData->dervusers;
                              $kerouserTemplate = $templateData->kerousers;
                              $templateMessage = $templateData->mailinglistgroupmessage;
                              $templatename = $templateData->mailinglistgroupname;


                require_once('./send/class.phpmailer.php');

               $mailer= new PHPMailer(true); //defaults to using php "mail()"; the true param means it will throw exceptions on errors, which we need to catch

               // Grab the FreakMailer class
                require_once('./send/MailClass.inc');

                // Grab our config settings
                require_once('./send/config.php');

              // Setup body
              $htmlBody = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                              <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                              <head>
                              <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                              <style>#title {padding-left:120px;padding-top:10px;font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif; font-size:22px; font-weight:bold; color:#fff;}</style>
                              </head>

                              <body>
                              <div style="background:
                                                                none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgb(6, 38,
                                                                97); width:780px;">
                              <img id="_x0000_i1030" style="padding-left:100px;padding-right:100px;"
                                                                    src="http://www.chandlersoil.com/images/newsletter/header.gif"
                                                                    alt="Chandlers Oil and Gas"
                                                                    border="0" height="112"
                                                                    width="580">
                                                                    <div id="title">" . $templateMessage . "</div>

                                                                    </div>
                              </body>
                              </html>
                              ';
               $textBody = "$templateData->mailinglistgroupmessage";

              // instantiate the class
              $mailer = new FreakMailer();

              // Get the user's Email
              $sql = mysql_query("SELECT leadname,businessname,email,mailtype FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead WHERE keromailinglist='$kerouserTemplate' AND dervmailinglist='$dervuserTemplate' AND gasoilmailinglist='$gasoiluserTemplate'");

              while($row = mysql_fetch_object($sql))
              {
                  // Send the emails in this loop.
                  $name = $row->leadname;
                   $name = $row->businessname;
                    $to_email = $row->email;
                    $mailtype = $row->mailtype;
                  if(!empty($row->businessname))
                  {
                      $name .= ' '.$row->leadname;
                  }
                  $to_name = $name;
                  if($row->MailType == 'html')
                  {
                      $mailer->Body = str_replace('{name}', $name, $htmlBody);
                      $mailer->IsHTML(true);
                      $mailer->AltBody = str_replace('{name}', $name, $textBody);
                      $mailer->AddAddress($to_email, $name);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      $mailer->Body = str_replace('{name}', $name, $textBody);
                      $mailer->isHTML(false);
                          $mailer->AddAddress($to_email, $name);
                  }
                  $mailer->Send();
                  $mailer->ClearAddresses();
                  $mailer->ClearAttachments();
                  $mailer->IsHTML(false);
                  echo "Mail sent to: $name - $to_email<br />";
              }

              ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

```
$name = $row->leadname;
$name = $row->businessname;
```

... which leads me to assume your variable is overwritten....

This was a small code portion, if you encounter it in more elaborate code, and you don't know where a variable is altered, you could use this little trick

```
class WhereIsThisAltered{
     protected $value;
     function __construct($value){
          $this->value = $value;
     }
     function __toString(){
         return $this->value;
     }
     function __destruct(){
         echo "Instance with value:{$this->value} desctructed";
         debug_print_backtrace();
     }
}

$name = new WhereIsThisAltered($row->leadname);
```

Comment: Thanks for that !, I renamed $name to $businessname and it is working now :-)

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing single and double quotes. Change this line:

```
<div id="title">" . $templateMessage . "</div>
```

to

```
<div id="title">' . $templateMessage . '</div>
```